# Как улучшить(сократить) код?

Tags: python-3.x, json, pyqt5

Уже давно написал один цикл который заполняет таблицу по заданным значениям и ключам из файла json. Но меня сильно беспокоит его неэффективность. Во-первых это занимает очень много места(это не критично). Во-вторых к этому циклу добавиться еще минимум 4 таких же цикла, это уже критично. Помимо 1600 строк бесполезного кода это еще наверняка отразиться на быстродействии. Хотел бы узнать, какие могут быть варианты оптимизации?

Ссылка на код: [!осторожно, много бесполезного кода!](https://pastebin.com/56KXHPsE)

```py
    column1 = []
    column2 = []
    column3 = []

    for list_dict in json_table.values():
        for key_value in list_dict:
            keys = key_value.keys()
            value = key_value.values()
            for key_item in keys:
                column1.append(key_item)       # значения для 1 столбца
            for value_item in value:
                column2.append(value_item[0])  # значения 2 столбца
                column3.append(value_item[1:])
                # списки со значениями для 3 столбца


 for row in range(table.rowCount()):                                    #цикл заполнения таблицы
        gbox = QGridLayout()
        framebox = QFrame()
        framebox.setLayout(gbox)
        table.setCellWidget(row, 2, framebox)

        farmer = QLabel()
        farmer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        farmer.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':1_Farmers.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        worker = QLabel()
        worker.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        worker.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':2_Workers.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        artisan = QLabel()
        artisan.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        artisan.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':3_Artisans.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        engineer = QLabel()
        engineer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        engineer.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':4_Engineers.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        investor = QLabel()
        investor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        investor.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':5_Investors.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        scholar = QLabel()
        scholar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        scholar.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':6_Icon_resident_scholars_0.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        tourist = QLabel()
        tourist.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        tourist.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(':7_Tourists.webp').scaled(25, 25))
        for pics in (farmer, worker, artisan, engineer,
                     investor, scholar, tourist):
            pics.setStyleSheet("background-color: ")
        
        column_pop = column1.pop(0)                                     # Значения для 1 столбца, а так же ключи для проверки в if
        
        list_values = column3.pop(0)                                    # Значения берутся из json файла, 
        if len(list_values) == 2:
            if column_pop in ("Fish.webp",                              
                              "Schnapps.webp",
                              "Work_clothes.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(farmer, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(worker, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Sausages.webp", "Bread.webp",
                                "Soap.webp", "Beer.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(worker, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(artisan, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Canned_food.webp",
                                "Sewing_machines.webp",
                                "Fur_Coats.webp", "Rum.webp",
                                "Advanced_rum_roaster.png"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(artisan, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(engineer, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Glasses.webp",
                                "High_wheeler.webp",
                                "Pocket_watch.webp",
                                "Light_bulb.webp", "Coffee.webp",
                                "Advanced_coffee_roaster.png",
                                "Chewing_Gum.webp",
                                "Typewriters.webp",
                                "Violins.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(engineer, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(investor, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Champagne.webp", "Jewelry.webp",
                                "Gramophone.webp",
                                "Steam_carriages.webp",
                                "Cigars.webp", "Chocolate.webp",
                                "Biscuits.webp", "Cognac.webp",
                                "Billiard_Tables.webp",
                                "Toys.webp"):
                if column_pop == "Jewelry.webp":
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    gbox.addWidget(investor, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(tourist, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                else:
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    gbox.addWidget(investor, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(scholar, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Bowler_hats.webp",
                                "Icon_hibiscus_tea_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tapestries_0.webp",
                                "Icon_wat_stew_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tobacco_pipes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_leather_shoes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_suits_0.webp",
                                "Icon_telephones_0.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(investor, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            else:
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        elif len(list_values) == 3:
            if column_pop in ("Fish.webp", "Schnapps.webp",
                              "Work_clothes.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                    font-size: 14px;")
                gbox.addWidget(farmer, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(worker, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(artisan, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Sausages.webp", "Bread.webp",
                                "Soap.webp", "Beer.webp"):
                if column_pop == "Bread.webp":
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                    labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                        font-size: 14px;")
                    gbox.addWidget(worker, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(artisan, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(tourist, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
                else:
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                    labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                        font-size: 14px;")
                    gbox.addWidget(worker, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(artisan, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(engineer, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Canned_food.webp",
                                "Sewing_machines.webp",
                                "Fur_Coats.webp", "Rum.webp",
                                "Advanced_rum_roaster.png"):
                if column_pop == "Canned_food.webp":
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                    labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                        font-size: 14px;")
                    gbox.addWidget(artisan, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(engineer, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(scholar, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
                if column_pop == "Fur_Coats.webp":
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                    labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                        font-size: 14px;")
                    gbox.addWidget(artisan, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(engineer, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(tourist, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1,  1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
                if column_pop in ("Rum.webp",
                                  "Advanced_rum_roaster.png"):
                    labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                    labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                    labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                    labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                        font-size: 14px;")
                    gbox.addWidget(artisan, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(engineer, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(scholar, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                    gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Glasses.webp",
                                "High_wheeler.webp",
                                "Pocket_watch.webp",
                                "Light_bulb.webp", "Coffee.webp",
                                "Advanced_coffee_roaster.png",
                                "Chewing_Gum.webp",
                                "Typewriters.webp",
                                "Violins.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                    font-size: 14px;")
                gbox.addWidget(engineer, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(investor, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Champagne.webp", "Jewelry.webp",
                                "Gramophone.webp",
                                "Steam_carriages.webp",
                                "Cigars.webp", "Chocolate.webp",
                                "Biscuits.webp", "Cognac.webp",
                                "Billiard_Tables.webp",
                                "Toys.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                    font-size: 14px;")
                gbox.addWidget(investor, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Bowler_hats.webp",
                                "Icon_hibiscus_tea_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tapestries_0.webp",
                                "Icon_wat_stew_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tobacco_pipes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_leather_shoes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_suits_0.webp",
                                "Icon_telephones_0.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                    font-size: 14px;")
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
            else:
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                labe2 = QLabel(list_values[1])
                labe3 = QLabel(list_values[2])
                labe3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Roboto; \
                                    font-size: 14px;")
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 2, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        else:
            if column_pop in ("Fish.webp", "Schnapps.webp",
                              "Work_clothes.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(farmer, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Sausages.webp", "Bread.webp",
                                "Soap.webp", "Beer.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(worker, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Canned_food.webp",
                                "Sewing_machines.webp",
                                "Fur_Coats.webp", "Rum.webp",
                                "Advanced_rum_roaster.png"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(artisan, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Glasses.webp",
                                "High_wheeler.webp",
                                "Pocket_watch.webp",
                                "Light_bulb.webp", "Coffee.webp",
                                "Advanced_coffee_roaster.png",
                                "Chewing_Gum.webp",
                                "Typewriters.webp",
                                "Violins.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(engineer, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Champagne.webp", "Jewelry.webp",
                                "Gramophone.webp",
                                "Steam_carriages.webp",
                                "Cigars.webp", "Chocolate.webp",
                                "Biscuits.webp", "Cognac.webp",
                                "Billiard_Tables.webp",
                                "Toys.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(investor, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            elif column_pop in ("Bowler_hats.webp",
                                "Icon_hibiscus_tea_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tapestries_0.webp",
                                "Icon_wat_stew_0.webp",
                                "Icon_tobacco_pipes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_leather_shoes_0.webp",
                                "Icon_suits_0.webp",
                                "Icon_telephones_0.webp"):
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(scholar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            else:
                labe = QLabel(list_values[0])
                gbox.addWidget(tourist, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                gbox.addWidget(labe, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

самый лучший совет - заново сесть и на бумаге спроектировать алгоритм, потому что можно экономить "на спичках", уменьшать код, не повышая его эффективности или делая более непонятным

например вместо текущих

```
for list_dict in json_table.values():
    for key_value in list_dict:
        keys = key_value.keys()
        value = key_value.values()
        for key_item in keys:
            column1.append(key_item)       # значения для 1 столбца
        for value_item in value:
            column2.append(value_item[0])  # значения 2 столбца
            column3.append(value_item[1:]) # списки со значениями для 3 столбца
```

можно сделать:

```
for list_dict in json_table.values():
    for key_value in list_dict:
        column1.extend(key_value.keys())                   # значения для 1 столбца
        column2.extend(v[0] for v in key_value.values())   # значения 2 столбца
        column2.extend(v[1:] for v in key_value.values())  # списки со значениями для 3 столбца
```

и т.д.